# My Macbook Pro with Lion OS is slow. How to speed it up

Tags: macos, google-chrome, memory, osx-lion, macbook

I am running on Macbook with 2.4GHz Core 2 Duo processor, 4GB DDR3 RAM, Lion OS X 10.8.4.
Last weeks I have noticed that the work with it is so slow, for example browsers.

Doesn't matter whether I use Google Chrome or Safari, bot in bot cases when I click on the new tab, I see the rolling colourful circle and in 2-4 seconds is displayed the new tab and I can type an URL address.

This makes the work with this machine incredibly slow. I checked if in the background is not running disc indexing, but it doesn't.

Had anyone the same or similar issue? How could I fix this behavior and speed up my MBP?
What software to use for cleaning up the MBP?

Thank you

Comment: Does this happen everytime or only sometimes (e.g. after many hours/days since boot) ?
What about RAM availibility (free, not inactive) ? and disk usage (in percentage) ?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can slow down your MBP is you might have too little space left. Try free up some space might help.

You will get a lot more performance if you upgrade your RAM since you only have 4GB.

Comment: I have ±10GB free space. Yea, I am thinking about upgrading to 8GB total...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.techradar.com/news/computing/apple/speed-up-your-mac-get-the-best-performance-from-os-x-1078459#null

> Speed up your Mac: get the best performance from OS X Tutorial Is your
>   Mac showing its age and slowing down? Here's how to put a spring back
>   in its step...